# model.update() not updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to add a new element to an array.

This is the code:

```
var findEditThenSave = function(personId, done) {
  var foodToAdd = 'hamburger';
  var foodArray = [];



  Person.findById(personId, function (err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    done(null, data);
    foodArray = data.favoriteFoods;
    console.log("foodArray inside findById: ", foodArray);
    foodArray.push(foodToAdd);
    var updateObj = {favoriteFoods: foodArray};
    console.log(updateObj)


    Person.update({_id: personId}, updateObj, function(err, raw) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("There was an error");

      }

      console.log("Updated successfully");
      console.log("foodArray inside update function:", foodArray);
    });
  });




};
```

This is the whole code on Glitch: https://glitch.com/edit/#!/holly-maroon-pony?path=myApp.js%3A226%3A0

This is the console log for a POST request:

```
POST
foodArray inside findById:  ["spaghetti"]
{ favoriteFoods: ["spaghetti","hamburger"] }
(node:8943) DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.
Updated successfully
foodArray inside update function: ["spaghetti","hamburger"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `async` and `await` while making these updates.

```
var findEditThenSave = async function(personId, done){
    var foodToAdd = 'hamburger';
    var foodArray = [];
    var updateObj;

    try{
        var data=await Person.findById(personId);
        done(null, data);
        foodArray = data.favoriteFoods;
        console.log("foodArray inside findById: ", foodArray);
        foodArray.push(foodToAdd);
        updateObj = {favoriteFoods: foodArray};
        console.log(updateObj)
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }

    try{
        await Person.update({_id: personId}, updateObj);
        console.log("Updated successfully");
        console.log("foodArray inside update function:", foodArray);
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
};
```

Comment: It's still not updating.

Comment: Please check now! the `updateObj` was `undefined` as it's scope was within the 1st `try catch` block. Now I've made it visible to both `try catch` blocks. It should definitely work now.

Comment: Now the mongoDB database seems to be empty, but I'm getting log `foodArray inside findById:  ["spaghetti"]` so I guess it can not be empty.

Is there a delay with mongoDB Atlas that can cause this? (Is that normal that Atlas is not showing current state?)

Comment: It sure takes some time to update in `Atlas`. Check in some time/

Comment: Please up-vote my answer if it helped you @Imestin!

Comment: I don't have enough reputation. (it will show later)

Comment: Okay, glad to have helped you! Is your Mongo Atlas updated with updated data now?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in your console:

```
(node:8943) DeprecationWarning: collection.update is             
deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.
Updated successfully
```

So you can get through this using `Person.updateOne` instead of `Person.update` 
Hope it helps

Comment: yes, this would certainly solve the problem, but I need to do this with model.update(), because it's a freeCodeCamp lesson. The other methods all worked. In this lesson it wants to teach the legacy method. If it's absolutly not working anymore, I should write to fCC that it's not working anymore, but I think it can work somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just planning to `update` a document and return the updated document you can do something like this

```js
function update(personId) {
  var foodToAdd = "hamburger";
  const person = Person.findByIdAndUpdate(
    personId,
    { $push: { favoriteFoods: foodToAdd } },
    { new: true },
    function (err, result) {
      if (err) console.log(err);
      else console.log(result);
    }
  );
};
```